# jsdom with CRA throwing TypeError _ownerDocument null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, jsdom

I have a craco project that runs just fine, but when running tests with jest it throws the following error. I don't even have jsdom installed, it appears to be a peer dependency of craco? No idea how to solve this one, but can clarify any questions in the comments since I don't know what is causing this.

```
/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:111
      referrer: _ownerDocument.URL,
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'URL')
    at new XMLHttpRequestImpl (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:111:32)
    at Object.exports.setup (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/XMLHttpRequest.js:62:12)
    at new XMLHttpRequest (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/XMLHttpRequest.js:101:22)
    at /Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:514:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:507:12)
    at /Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/src/functions/create-installation-request.ts:54:51
    at /Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/src/functions/common.ts:94:24
    at step (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
```

I noticed firebase is a part of the stack trace. Is it possible this is related?

Comment: could you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Can you please provide the full reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging I found out it was related to the `getAnalytics` function exported from the `firebase/analytics` package. The fix for me was to mock the `getAnalytics` function as it wasn't required for testing purposes anyways.

Comment: Maybe you can give a deeper explanation on how you "mocked" the function?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few tips for future uses:

- When you encounter errors, especially the ones with long traceback errors (e.g. HTTP requests), you should look out for the errors:

```
    at /Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/src/functions/create-installation-request.ts:54:51
    at /Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/src/functions/common.ts:94:24
    at step (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/munsterberg/code/creatordao/creatordao-portal/node_modules/@firebase/installations/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
```

Here `@firebase` package is mentioned quite a few times, `functions` too, so you can deduce it has something to with it, especially with it under `node_module`.

- Quick point out on `mock functions`, which are:

> special functions that allow us to track how a particular function is called by external code

So mocking a function can actually be important, especially when running tests with external packages and files.

Related:

- [Pluralsight.com guides](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-does-jest.fn()-work)